How to get a UsedLicences count for login-based Digital Experience licenses?
When I query the UserLicense object using:
select Id, Name, Status, LicenseDefinitionKey, UsedLicenses, TotalLicenses
from UserLicense
where Id in ...

I get this result:

where the UsedLicences count is 0 instead of the value 1 that I expect (last row). The Companies UI displays the correct value of 1 (last row):

This is for the login-based license - see Experience Cloud User Licenses for details of that. The member-based number is correct.
What is the best work-around to get the correct number of UsedLicences in Apex code? An aggregate query of User? Or am I missing something here?

Time-based aggregation/accounting is the difference between the two. Whether it's simply an undocumented "feature" of how the rollup works or a bug is a matter of argument. Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378326/retrieving-license-consumption-stats-for-a-customer-community-login-license

Thanks @identigral. The current documentation that I linked to suggests (in my mind at least) that there is a UserLicense.TotalLicenses limit (number of users) that is separate from the UserLicense.MonthlyLogins* limit (login counts) and the Companies UI seems to reflect that. Just appears to be no counting of UserLicense.UsedLicenses.

Monthly in UserLicense is not visible to tenants. Looking at the few of our customer orgs, the UserLicense count matches Company Info. Our take is that you're off by 1 due to timing but perhaps it's a more subtle bug. Open a support case, if you think and/or care that this delta is going to grow to >> 1
